# Material menu without button

Tags: jquery, material-design

I am using the [getmdl.io](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#menus-section) library for several things. Now I would like to fire the menu without using the `button`, but with a `div` instead, but my code does not work. Help would be great!

```
<div id="menu1"><i class="material-icons mi-mmenu">menu</i> Match Menu</div>

<ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--top-left mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect"
    data-mdl-for="menu1">
  <li class="mdl-menu__item">Some Action</li>
  <li class="mdl-menu__item">Another Action</li>
  <li disabled class="mdl-menu__item">Disabled Action</li>
  <li class="mdl-menu__item">Yet Another Action</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you have JavaScript code that shows the menu and its items on click?

Comment: Probably this here https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.js. But I have no idea, what to do in there.

Comment: Do you not see your menu when you load your page in a browser?

Comment: Yes, it is hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/uybsr4dm/1/. You need to change the position of the items in the menu to `mdl-menu--lower-left`. Because when you click the menu, the items show up but they were getting cutoff.

```
<div id="menu1"><i class="material-icons mi-mmenu">menu</i> Match Menu</div>

<ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--lower-left mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect"
    data-mdl-for="menu1">
  <li class="mdl-menu__item">Some Action</li>
  <li class="mdl-menu__item">Another Action</li>
  <li disabled class="mdl-menu__item">Disabled Action</li>
  <li class="mdl-menu__item">Yet Another Action</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help! So the problem was the position of the ul? The code looks the same.

Comment: Yes, there is nothing wrong with your code. It is just the positioning of the `ul`. Changing `<ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--top-left` to `<ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--lower-left` fixes the issue.

Comment: But only when the buttons are located at the top, right :) Mine are at the bottom of the page.

Comment: yeah, it is pushed `250px` down and works with `ul` being `<ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--top-left`. https://jsfiddle.net/uybsr4dm/2/